# How to ignore a URL in a redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, magento, url-rewriting

I have the following redirect in my store:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I want to ignore the redirection for
`www.mydomain.net/admin`

because its my backend to manage my store and now I cant access my admin because of the URL redirection I set.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy enough to just reverse your line to a negation statement so that it applies to everything that does not match the paths you don't want to rewrite:

```
RewriteRule !^(admin/.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or more preferably just add another rewrite conditional to exclude the admin directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
```

They both should work but the second one looks nicer.